# Is there a way I can disable Tampermonkey for a specifiic site on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tampermonkey

I only have two scripts and one of them, not sure which, is causing an issue with a photo gallery on a certain site. I didn't write those scripts; they're both adblockers; I have no idea how to write scripts myself, so I don't want to tamper with them. Instead, since neither of those scripts are useful for the site in question, I'd just like to disable Tampermonkey as a whole or script-by-script upon entering that site. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, go to Tampermonkey options (dashboard), scroll to "blacklist" and paste the url there.

Comment: I don't see "blacklist" under the options in the dashboard.

Comment: Click `Settings` tab on that dashboard page: https://tampermonkey.net#security

Comment: Never mind I found it. My options were limited because I had it set to "Novice" settings. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After setting "Config mode" to "Advanced":

[image]

you can either:

1. Click the userscript icon while you're in the said site → Utilities → Blacklist example.com. If you change your mind, you can go to Settings → Security → edit Blacklisted pages → Save.

   [image]
2. (script-by-script) Click the userscript icon → click the arrow next to the userscript you want to disable → Exclude example.com:

   [image]

   If you change your mind, go to Tampermonkey's dashboard, open the userscript go to Settings → Includes/Excludes and edit "User excludes" accordingly:

   [image]